# Why does my batch script become unresponsive attempting to delete inexistant files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

The first part of my script:

```
@echo off
mode 34,18
color f0
del /s /q /f unsorted_frt.txt >nul 2>nul
del /s /q /f output_frt.txt >nul 2>nul
del /s /q /f frt.txt >nul 2>nul
del /s /q /f datas_futuros_rede_tan.txt >nul 2>nul
del /s /q /f datas_futuros_rede_tan.csv >nul 2>nul
del /s /q /f c:\datas_futuros_rede_tan.csv >nul 2>nul
(etc.)
```

Using Windows 7 it succeeds. But if the files to delete don't exist, the `.bat` file ignored this and continued anyway. I upgraded to Windows 10 and now, if the files to delete don't exist, the script fails entirely.

I need the script to continue despite this. How can I make that work on Windows 10? This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

It stops at this screen. If I delete this first part of the script, the rest runs normally.

Comment: Try this: >nul 2>&1

Comment: Nothing happened. It keeps stoped and didn't going.

Comment: At the top of your script turn echo on. Open up a command prompt and run the batch file from the command prompt. Update your question with the output.

Comment: Check it please.

Comment: I cannot replicate what you are experiencing.

Comment: 'ts so much strange. it just stop in that screen and don't go on...if idelet the commands `del` from the script, it run the rest normally...

Comment: The picture shows no errors as you redirect stderr to merge with stdout and redirect stdout to nul. Advise removal of redirection to see the errors.

Comment: You are absolutely positive there isn't a `timeout /T -1 >nul` or `pause >nul` in your script?

Comment: You are telling it to try and delete that file from every single directory on your C: drive. How fast do you think that should be?

Comment: This file size is 5KB, and sometimes it doesn't exist. So i can't belive that the script needs 2 min to ignore/del it. When i was using windows 7 this process ocurred in 3 seconds...I don't know if something in different im windows 10...

Comment: No way on earth it took 3 seconds when it has to traverse thousands of folders.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate here to edit the question to provide a solution to the problem. You have three possible options: 1) If you want to provide an answer for future readers, post an answer using the space provided for that below. You can answer your own question here, but you must do it properly.. 2) If you don't want to be bothered to write an answer, you can leave the post as is and wait for someone else to provide an answer for you, which you can accept. 3) If neither of the above works for you, you can delete the question using the link below the tags.

Comment: Recheck your commands. `/q` is for wildcard which you are not using any wildcards. `/s` for recursion which is needed? The recursion may take some time.

Comment: I rolled back your edit **again**. **DO NOT** post the answer as an edit to the post. See my previous comment. If you want to provide an answer, do so using the space below with the heading **Your Answer** to do so.

Comment: @Ken White call the FBI

Comment: I've flagged this post for moderator attention for your continued misconduct after rolling back your edit. If you don't want to follow the guidelines here, feel free to go somewhere else to ask for help.

Comment: I posted your answer as a new answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

Answer previously posted on question:

The problem is occurring in this line `del /s /q /f c:\datas_futuros_rede_tan.csv >nul 2>nul` So i changed it to `del /s /q /f "c:\datas_futuros_rede_tan.csv" >nul 2>nul` So, after more or less 2 minutes stopped in the same screen (like the image above), it starts to keep going.

Comment: The quotes shouldn't have made any difference as there were not any spaces or special characters in the file path.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually a good idea to test whether or not the file exists before deleting it.

```
IF EXIST "unsorted_frt.txt" DO (DEL "unsorted.txt")
```

A FOR loop can help in deleting a large list of files. This list would presume that all files except the last one are in the current working directory. If the file names contain SPACE or other special characters, then they need to be quoted.

```
SET FILE_LIST=^
unsorted_frt.txt ^
output_frt.txt ^
frt.txt ^
datas_futuros_rede_tan.txt ^
datas_futuros_rede_tan.csv ^
c:\datas_futuros_rede_tan.csv

FOR %%f IN (%FILE_LIST%) DO (
    IF EXIST "%%~f" DO (DEL "%%~f" >NUL 2>NUL)
)
```